# Google Analytics update frequency

Tags: google-analytics

I've been searching to find information about when data in google analytics are "stable". When is it reliable to extract data from the API. I've read everything from 4 hours to 72 hours, but no official documentation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Data processing latency
>
> Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 visits > per day to Google Analytics will result in
>   the reports being refreshed only once a day. Daily  processing begins
>   at 12:00 UTC and continues for approximately 10 hours. This can delay
>   updates to reports and metrics for up to two days.

[From here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en).

Comment: I got around 20k likes for an article posted on my site, but my analytics has tracked only 6k of them, is it again due to the lag or something?

Comment: @trollster  there are some plugins/add-ons that block google analytics which could represent at least some of the difference. (results may vary depending on your audience demographics)

Answer (score 0):

For Google Analytics 4 (GA4), the times changed - see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11198161?hl=en

"Standard intraday" has a processing time of 4-8 hours.