# How long Google Analytics take to process the data from the day before?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the Analytics API to get the number of sessions from the previous day. I run this code at 5am.

When I get to the office at 9am, querying the API again (or seeing the analytics 
interface) returns me a higher number then the one I got at 5am.

So, how long does Analytics take to update data from day before? Is this the issue or could it be something else? I was thinking could be something timezone related, but after getting my head through it, now, I think it can't.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics update frequency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226066/google-analytics-update-frequency)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes between 24 and 48 hours for data to finish processing in Google Analytics.  This is true for both the Google Analytics API and the Google Analytics website.   Although the website might get data before the API but I have been unable to prove this because by the time you make the request again both have changed.  Its probably not related to time zone its from the time the hit was recorded.

[Data limits](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)

> **Data processing latency**
>  Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard
>   accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics
>   will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. This can
>   delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. To restore
>   intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions your account sends
>   to < 200,000 per day. For Premium accounts, this limit is extended to
>   2 billion hits per month.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dalmTo. I did tried to Google this, but could't really find a straight answer.

Comment: Sometimes you have to know what to Google took me a while to find this the first time.   Data Latency who would have thought ...

Comment: @DaImTo, actually I would have thought so (seeing that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226066/google-analytics-update-frequency/22226164#22226164) :-)

Comment: Its probably a duplicate of 6 different questions, I know I have also answered a bunch with the same as well.  was faster to answer it then find the duplicate but you are probably right :)